# Simulating data between correlated count variable and a continuous variable

Tags: r, count, simulation

Does anybody know how I could possible simulate data with a correlation between a count variable and a continuous variable? Right now the best idea that I have is to just transform the count variable to make it approximately normal, and then to simulate the data using this R code:

```
set.seed(2018) 
x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
y = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = .29*x, sqrt(1-.3^2))      
cor(x,y)
```

However, I really think it would be preferable if I could actually make Y a count variable (because they tend to typically be right-skewed). Also, I want to be able to specify specific correlations between x and y. E.g., simulate data with a 0.5 correlation between x and y etc.

**Edit: I'm still looking for help!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runif` to simulate the continuous variable, then feed the result as the lambda (rate) parameter of `rpois`:

```r
set.seed(1)

continuous <- runif(100, 0, 10)
counts <- rpois(100, continuous)
plot(continuous, counts)
```

[image]

```r
cor(counts, continuous)
#> [1] 0.7852701
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I realize now that this wasn't clear from my question: Why I'd like to do is be able to specify the correlation ahead of time. I'm not sure how I could simulate data with say a 0.5 correlation with your method. I'll try and edit the original post to make that clear.